# How to get rid of PHP errors in Terminal after Mavericks upgrade

Tags: php, mcrypt

I recently upgraded my Mac to Mavericks, the new OS.  As part of the upgrade, Apple updated PHP to 5.4.  I installed the mcrypt extension for PHP, which went just fine in terms of mcrypt working and no installation errors.

But it had an unwanted side effect.  Now, when I run a PHP command (like `php -v`) at the command line in Terminal, I get these errors:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/php_pdo_firebird.dll' - dlopen(/php_pdo_firebird.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/php_pdo_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/php_pdo_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/php_pdo_oci.dll' - dlopen(/php_pdo_oci.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/php_pdo_odbc.dll' - dlopen(/php_pdo_odbc.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/php_pdo_pgsql.dll' - dlopen(/php_pdo_pgsql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - dlopen(/php_pdo_sqlite.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/php_sqlite3.dll' - dlopen(/php_sqlite3.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

As part of the mcrypt installation, I changed the `extension_dir` to the path for the mcrypt library.  I think this is why I am getting this error.  If I change the `extension_dir` to something else, it changes the path of these libraries in the error messages.  If I comment out `extension_dir`, I get the directory of the mcrypt extension, which is `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/mcrypt.so`.

So my question is, what path should I use so these libraries load?  What is the default that is set in a PHP installation?  I've Googled and can't find it.  I thought it was `./`, but that doesn't work.  I believe, actually, that that line is commented out in the default installation, but like I said, commenting out the `extension_dir` doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried fully reinstall PHP?

Comment: I run a Macports version of PHP in parallel to the OS version, which saves me from changing something that the OS might need. You can install 5.3, 5.4 and 5.5 in any combination from Macports alongside the default OS install. Another benefit is you can do `sudo port install php54-mcrypt` (or whatever extension) and it will fetch it, compile it and install it with no fuss.

Comment: No, I was hoping to avoid that because then I lose mcrypt

Comment: I don't use mac, but sure can't you add the extension after reinstall?

Comment: Yes, it's just a major hassle.

Comment: @halfer, I didn't completely read your comment.  I may try that.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries, I updated it a few minutes after my initial comment. Ping me here if you need further help. I've heard that some people prefer HomeBrew for the same purpose, but MacPorts is now (imho) so stable I see no reason to move.

Comment: I use Homebrew, which I believe has a parallel package for PHP and Mcrypt.

Comment: brew has formulae for php53 php54 and php55. josegonzales put together several plugins for each version. mcrypt, gmagick, and others. Install brew to find out: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)", then brew doctor, and brew update to get everything up-to-date.